# Why we cannot implement collection interface directly by a concrete class?

Tags: java, collections

`Collection` interface defines the most common general methods which can be applicable for any `Collection` object.

Some of the methods are like:

1) `boolean add(Object obj)`

2) `boolean addAll(Collection c)`

3) `boolean remove(Object obj)`

4) `boolean removeAll(Collection c)` (Removes particular group of
    objects.)

5) `boolean retainAll(Collection c)` (Removes all the elements except
    those present in `c`)

I want know the justification for this statement.

> There is no concrete class which implements collection interface
>   directly.

Comment: The purpose of the `Collections` _interface_ is that it defines a common set of behaviors which all collections share.  It is up to the particular implementation (e.g. list, set, map) as to _how_ it wants to implement these behaviors.

Comment: @SabirKhan Your edit just killed a big chunk of the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen- Something happened on SO, I didn't remove all of that. I simply quoted text and highlighted Collection as code.

Comment: I added part of question that was showing removed in my name. I was also wondering why would I do that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from creating a concrete direct implementation of `Collection`. However, such an implementation would probably have some additional properties not covered by the Collection contract.

For example, if the elements of your Collection implementation have an ordering, you might as well implement the List interface.

On the other hand, if the storage of your Collection implementation doesn't allow duplicate elements, you might as well implement the Set interface.

...and so on.

This may give you an idea why no concrete direct implementation was deemed necessary by the designers of the standard Collections library.

Comment: I would go further than "it is not necessary". It does not make sense because of  the things you mentioned.

Comment: @oopexpert Well, it doesn't make sense given the common scenarios we can think of. There might be some strange scenarios in which it would make sense, but the standard library probably aims to cover only the standard scenarios. One can always create their own Collection implementations if the standard implementations are not sufficient.

Comment: The problem is that you will have a really hard day to not accidentally add some properties that are not already defined by the Java API in sub interfaces and implemented by sub classes. After all if you use the Collection interface directly you cannot rely your code on any additional property like order or uniqueness etc because the contract doesn't tell you anything about it. The Collection interface does only define adding and removing elements so it's fully symmetric and every sub class serves this contract: Therefore it doesn't make sense to implement it directly.

Comment: On the notion of that "There might be some strange scenarios" I go totally with "strange". ;-)